# Can I sync two Android devices to the same U1 account?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, android

I wish to sync two Android mobiles (my spouse's and mine) and possibly one Android tablet to the same U1 account so we both can enjoy from streaming music.
I know it is possible to sync few devices/pc's to the same U1 account.

Does it also apply to the U1 music pack?
Will we be able to stream to the two devices simultaneously (not the same music, of course, just operating the two players separately but on the same time)?

Thanks, David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posed this question to the Ubuntu One support team and they confirmed that you can stream music to multiple devices at the same time.